# Mapping XML nodes into HTML form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, dom

I'd like to map XML node values (XML sent from AJAX script) into corresponding HTML form elements. So for example, an XML data;

```
<object>
  <fielda>John</fielda>
  <fieldc>Tailor</fieldc>
</object>
```

should be inserted by script into HTML form:

```
<form name="myform">
  <input name="fielda" value="">
  <input name="fieldc" value="">
</form>
```

The catch is that script should work generically for all objects (one cannot know in advance what fields will be given in XML, e.g. if "fieldx" is send in XML this script should fulfil document.myform.fieldx form element with corresponding value from XML). So this script should loop through all XML nodes and try to set values into HTML form.

Comment: Perhaps use XSL T is the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sc14nta/1/)**

## HTML

```
<form name="myform">
    <input name="fielda" value=""/>
    <input name="fieldc" value=""/>
</form>
<div id="status">Loading...</div>
```

## CSS

```
#status {
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

## JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    'url':'/echo/xml/',
    'method':'POST',
    'data':{
        xml:'<object>\n<fielda>John</fielda>\n<fieldc>Tailor</fieldc>\n</object>',
        'delay':1
    },
    'complete':function(xhr,status) {
        console.log(xhr);
        var form = document.myform;
        var root = xhr.responseXML.children[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < root.children.length; ++i) {
            var field = root.children[i];
            form[field.nodeName].value = field.textContent;
        } // end for
        document.getElementById('status').textContent = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't there in JS something like foreach(nodes as node) to loop through all children nodes instead of for() loop?

Comment: @sbrbot There's [`for (var propName in obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), but that loops through all owned and inherited property names of `obj`. There's [`for each (var propValue in obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in), but that loops through all owned and inherited property values of `obj`, and is deprecated. There's [`for (var x of obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), but that's new and experimental. And there's..

Comment: [`Array::forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), but that requires a lambda callback function and is messy. The traditional [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop is the best approach here for looping through an array.